# Use Netlify Functions for Server Side rendering

Tags: netlify

Netlify functions are usually located in some subpath like `/.netlify/functions`. Is it possible to make a function responsible for rendering every subpath in order to do Server Side rendering in a function?

Comment: I show how to make the default function path as one of your subpaths in my answer. Any valid page returned in the response would be valid. You can test using that method.

Answer (score 2):

There is the ability to create a **`rewrite rule`** in the redirects file to allow for a function to be at a prettier url end point.

Create a rewrite path to the function you are going to use as a subpath

`_redirects` [(see docs here)](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/)

```
/hello /.netlify/functions/sayhello 200
```

Make sure `/hello` path doesn't have a valid endpoint.

Using the below `sayhello` function you can pass query params also.

`sayhello.js`

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const {name = 'World'} = event.queryStringParameters;

  const message = `Hello to the ${name}!`
  callback(null, {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: `${message}`
  });
}
```

Calling `https://example.com/hello?name=talves`
responds with `Hello to the talves!` as the body.